# How to authenticate from local machine with gcloud storage keyfile

Tags: php, firebase-authentication, development-environment, gcloud

I'm setting up a connection between my php code (running on an external server) and the noSQL gCloud Firestore database. I develop locally. How do I authenticate ?

This is for a mac (10.14) running PHP 7 and Apache. I can successfully gcloud init.

In my PHP code:

```
$storage = new StorageClient([
    'keyfile' => json_decode(file_get_contents('myKey.json'), true)
]);
```

I expect it to run, but get:

Note: A keyfile was given, but it does not contain a project ID. This can indicate an old and obsolete keyfile, in which case you should create a new one.

The keyFile does contain a project ID. And I created a new service account private key.

Comment: Could you try `new StorageClient(["projectId" => "<PROJECT_ID>", "keyfile" => json_decode(file_get_contents('myKey.json'), true)])` and re-deploying to see if that solves the issue for you?

Comment: Hello, I develop this code locally, so do I need to deploy this locally every time? I am confused.

Comment: Hello, what I meant was *running* your application with the `StorageClient` instantiation I provided. Does the issue persist?

Comment: to be honest, I tried so many things but keep having problems. very frustrating..... thinking of outsourcing this bit. Anyway, where can I find a tutorial that will explain the local development of php code that connects from an external server to the Firestore?

Comment: You can look at the [Firestore Quickstart](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) which explains the steps necessary to interact with a Cloud Firestore database using PHP

Comment: Thank you @JKleinne I followed it and still get the same notice as stated in my original help question. What can I do else??

Answer (score 0):

It works, I had to start the firestore emulator.
$ firebase emulators:start --only firestore